# cellの外側を確立することはできるのか

Tags: swift, ios, swift4, swift5

今、collectionViewのcellの外をタップしたときに画面遷移したいのですがcollectionViewCellの外側というのを判定することができません。
下の写真の黄色い部分です。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

画面遷移のコードは

```
        outsideCell.gestureRecognizers = [UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.outsideTouch(_:)))]
```

教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: `outsideCell`に何型のどんなインスタンスをどうやって代入したかが解らないと、どう答えたら良いのか誰にも解らないのではないでしょうか？そのあたりのコードを質問に具体的に記述すると回答を貰いやすくなると思います

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UICollectionView で表示してる cell の外側をタップされた時にコードを実行したいということでしたら、UICollectionView の backgroundView に UITapGestureRecognizer を追加した UIView を追加してください。

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleCollectionViewBackgroundTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        collectionView.backgroundView = view
    }

    @IBAction private func handleCollectionViewBackgroundTap(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Collection view background tapped")
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: なるほど、`UICollectionView`に`UIPanGestureRecognizer`を`add`するより、シンプルに処理できますね。リファレンスをちゃんと読む大事さを再確認しました。

Answer (score 1):

Collection Viewのセルをタップしたかどうかは、`UICollectionViewDelegate`プロトコルの`collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`メソッドで知ることができます。そしてCollection Viewは`UIView`のサブクラスですから、`UITapGestureRecognizer`を`add`して、タップを検知することができます。ここまでは、質問者さんには既知のことと思います。
そして、プログラミングには、数学の集合の概念、否定（NOT）、論理和（OR）、論理積（AND）が必須であることも既知のことと思います。「Collection Viewをタップした」という命題と、「セルをタップした」という命題を使い、否定と論理積を組みわせて、「Collection Viewがタップされ、かつセルがタップされていない」、すなわち「セルの外側がタップされた」を知ることができます。

Collection Viewのインスタンスを`collectionView`とすると、`UITapGestureRecognizer`の組み込みは、

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped(_:))) // セレクタのメソッド名は、任意で。
tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

ただ`UITapGestureRecognizer`を組み込むだけだと、セルのタップがブロックされてしまうので、2行目`tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false`で、そのブロックをキャンセルしておきます。

Comment: この回答は、質問者さんのReplyに応じて更新する用意があります。

Comment: その否定と論理積の組み合わせのコードを教えていただくことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: はい可能です。サンプルコードも書き上げて動作確認済みです。私は、キャッチボールをしたいと思っています。トスバッティングのような、一方だけボールを投げ、他方がバットで打つだけということは考えていません。いまボールは質問者さんの側にあります。質問を更新して、素晴らしいQ&Aになるようにしてください。私も頑張ります。